# Remove custom UIView randomly Not Working swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am building an iOS Application in swift 3, where I am creating dynamic UIView. I need to remove custom view randomly.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var myView: subView!
var y : CGFloat!
@IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    y = 1
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
func cancelbutton(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    myView.removeFromSuperview()
}
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    y = y + 110
    myView = subView(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: y, width: 300, height: 100))

    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    myView.actionButton.addTarget(self, action: (#selector(cancelbutton(_:))), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(myView)

}
```

[image: subview]
above picture is my custom view

[image: sample output]
above picture is my sample output

when I click close button only one subview want to be close, which one I was selected. 
"Thanks in advance"

Comment: can you please try to explain a bit more precisely what exactly you are trying to achieve and what problems you have?

Comment: get button superview and remove that view

Comment: Are you trying to click the "x" button and use that to dismiss (remove) the light green container and all its contents? If so, can you show us what currently happens when you click the "x" button. It's always good to provide "expected behaviour" and "actual behaviour" so we can help debug and solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to achieve this,

I would suggest this.

// 1.
Make a new class inherited from UIView --> Say 'CustomView'.

// 2. 
Make 'Protocol' in 'CustomView' header. --> Say 'CustomViewDelegate'

```
@protocol CustomViewDelegate
@optional
- (void)didCloseButtonClickedWithView:(CustomView *)view;
@end
```

and delegate properly in header.

```
@property (nonatomic) id <CustomViewDelegate> delegate;
```

// 3.
in CustomView.m -->
Add action for 'Close' button. (via Storyboard or Programmatically, whatever you prefer).

```
- (void)closeClicked:(UIButton *)button
{

}
```

And call delegate using 'Protocol' method,

```
- (void)closeClicked:(UIButton *)button
{
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@(didCloseButtonClickedWithView:)])
    {
        [self.delegate didCloseButtonClickedWithView:self]; // passing self is 'CustomView'
    }
}
```

// 4. make 'CustomView' objects in your ViewController.

```
CustomView *view = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
view.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

// 5. 
implement CustomViewDelegate in your ViewController.

```
- (void)didCloseButtonClickedWithView:(CustomView *)view
{
    // you will get action of close button here
    // remove your view here.
    [view removeFromSuperview];

    // Additional tips:
    // Re-arrange frames for other views.
}
```